# kotlin extension function casting

Tags: java, kotlin

I'd like to implement two extensions functions applied to two interfaces which inherits each other (from a java lib)

```java
public interface RelativeDateOffset {...}
public interface AdjustedRelativeDateOffset extends RelativeDateOffset {...}
```

my extensions are:

```kotlin
fun RelativeDateOffset.getOrResolve(){ 
   println("parent: relative")
}

fun AdjustedRelativeDateOffset.getOrResolve(){
   println("child: adjusted")
}
```

But, when creating an explicit object of type `AdjustedRelativeDateOffset`, the called function is the one from the parent interface:

```kotlin
lateinit var myObject: AdjustedRelativeDateOffset

myObject.getOrResolve() //prints "parent: relative"

//even when casting

(myObject as AdjustedRelativeDateOffset).getOrResolve() //prints "parent: relative"
```

Is there a mention of this behavior somewhere ? Kotlin doc didn't helped me so far to understand, and possibly to resolve this problem.

Thx

Comment: Are both extensions declared in the same file?

Comment: As in my experiment, it works fine: prints "child: adjusted" if the type is AdjustedRelativeDateOffset

Comment: hmm, tbh I didn't mocked myself with the code provided in description. maybe i've over simplified my implementation for the sake of simplicity. I should dig in that direction